# Reading/writing excel using ODBC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, odbc

I am writing a MFC program to create a dialogue with two buttons(read and write), when read button  
  is clicked, the function of reading excel is called. After I run the program and click
 the read button, the VS(2012) compiler shows database error that Microsoft Jet can't find the 
 'demo' file, which is the file read function is supposed to read. Can anyone tell
me what went wrong? Thank you so much! And Here is my code.

```
    void CMFCApplication1Dlg::WriteToExcel()
    {
        CDatabase database;
        CString sDriver = _T("Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)"); 
        CString sExcelFile = _T("d:\\demo.xls"); 
        CString

 sSql;
    TRY
    {

        sSql.Format(_T("DRIVER={%s};DSN='';FIRSTROWHASNAMES=1;READONLY=FALSE;CREATE_DB=\"%s\";DBQ=%s"),sDriver, sExcelFile, sExcelFile);

    if (database.OpenEx(sSql,CDatabase::noOdbcDialog))
    {

        sSql = "CREATE TABLE demo (Name TEXT,Age NUMBER)";
        database.ExecuteSQL(sSql);


        sSql = "INSERT INTO demo (Name,Age) VALUES ('qinshujin',32)";
        database.ExecuteSQL(sSql);

        sSql = "INSERT INTO demo (Name,Age) VALUES ('jiyingjun',28)";
        database.ExecuteSQL(sSql);

        sSql = "INSERT INTO demo (Name,Age) VALUES ('zhangqi',28)";
        database.ExecuteSQL(sSql);
    }

    database.Close();
    }
        CATCH_ALL(e)
    {
        TRACE1("Excel driver is not installed: %s", sDriver);
    }
    END_CATCH_ALL;
}



CString CMFCApplication1Dlg::GetExcelDriver()
{
    char szBuf[2001];
    WORD cbBufMax = 2000;
    WORD cbBufOut;
    char *pszBuf = szBuf;
    CString sDriver;


    if (!SQLGetInstalledDrivers(szBuf, cbBufMax, &cbBufOut))
        return _T("");


    do
    {
        if (strstr(pszBuf, "Excel") != 0)
        {

            sDriver = CString(pszBuf);
            break;
        }
        pszBuf = strchr(pszBuf, '\0') + 1;
    } while (pszBuf[1] != '\0');

    return sDriver;
}


void CMFCApplication1Dlg::ReadFromExcel()
{
    CDatabase database;
    CString sSql;
    CString sItem1, sItem2;
    CString sDriver;
    CString sDsn;
    CString sFile = "d:\\demo.xls"; 
    sDriver = GetExcelDriver();
if (sDriver.IsEmpty())
{

    cout << "NO Excel Driver!" << endl;
    return;
}

sDsn.Format("ODBC;DRIVER={%s};DSN='';DBQ=%s", sDriver, sFile);

TRY
{
    database.Open(NULL, false, false, sDsn);

CRecordset recset(&database);

sSql = "SELECT Name, Age "
    "FROM demo "
    "ORDER BY Name ";

recset.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, sSql, CRecordset::readOnly);

while (!recset.IsEOF())
{
    recset.GetFieldValue("Name", sItem1);
    recset.GetFieldValue("Age", sItem2);
    cout << sItem1 << "\t" << sItem2 << endl;

    recset.MoveNext();
}

database.Close();

}
    CATCH(CDBException, e)
{
    AfxMessageBox("Error: " + e->m_strError);
}
END_CATCH;
}
```

Comment: could you post the error message. If the file exists, about all that is left is permission. Also post the resulting `sSql` string you are using. And you can just hardwire that string for testing.I can open a file with `L"ODBC;DRIVER={MICROSOFT excel DRIVER (*.xls)};DBQ=C:\\cpp\\empty_test.xls";`

Comment: OK , I will post you the error message and what is sSql string? Did you run my code?

Comment: The error is The Microsoft Jet Database Engine cannot open the file '(unknown)'"

Comment: I did not do it in an MFC app, I used a console app. There is only one relevant line, `database.Open(..)` Make that work with a hard coded argument and forget the rest of the code.

Comment: What do you mean? Should I focus on the database.open() line?

Comment: Just use a hard coded argument with `database.Open`. Like the one I posted above.

Comment: And could you tell me what is hard coded argument please? Thank you !

Comment: `database.Open(NULL, false, false, L"ODBC;DRIVER={MICROSOFT excel DRIVER (*.xls)};DBQ=C:\\cpp\\empty_test.xls");` Your xls file does exist and you are running as administrator?

Comment: What does 'L' mean? When I type L, the VS compiler send me an error message.

Comment: I use unicode builds, just delete the `L`. At that, you should be building with unicode. MS keeps saying they will depreciate multi-byte.

Comment: I am sorry, it still doesn't work. The compiler gave me a break point this time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205351/discussion-between-lakeweb-and-liu).

Comment: My code finally worked before we continued our discussion in chat . I wan't aware of that. The problem is exactly what you told me--permission. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, ok. Just saw this, glad you got it.